# "onlyOwner" Function restrict the call from child contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, import, contract-upgrading

I have a basic knowledge of solidity. I am trying to create an upgradable ERC20 Token. For that, I create `TokenStorage` contract and `Logic` contract and trying to write the `Proxy` contract.

In the `Logic` contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./TokenStorage.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";
import './Ownable.sol';
```

In the `TokenStorage` contract:

```
function addTotalSupply(uint256 _value) public onlyOwner {
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_value);
}
```

When I call `balances.addTotalSupply(_amount)` from `Logic.mint()`, I get error.

If I remove `onlyOwner` in `addTotalSupply`, it executes correctly.

**Note** All contracts are deployed using the same account.

Please help me to understand why this happens.

Please Share me a proper guide to creating an upgradeable ERC20 Token is much appreciable

Thank you. 
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You should either inherit `Logic ` from `TokenStorage`, or implement a new modifier called `onlyLogic` and use it instead of `onlyOwner`.

Comment: Thank you @goodvibration for your reply. But in upgradeable contract, Logic may change in future how can I inherit logic in Tokenstorage. I am following the article to write this https://medium.com/carbon-money/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-full-stack-upgradeable-erc-20-dapp-81a7e35e374 .

Answer (score 5):

Sammu Sundar.

It happens because your Logic contract is not an owner/creator of the Storage contract (from what I understood).

In this case, it would be better to introduce an additional access control mechanism. You may call it `manager` or `admin`. The key point is to allow certain operations to be called not only by the owner.

You could use something like this as a base contract for entities that should be *managed* and *owned*.

```
contract Managed is Owned {          

    mapping (address => bool) public managers;

    constructor() public Owned() {
        managers[owner] = true;
    }

    /**@dev Allows execution by managers only */
    modifier managerOnly {
        require(managers[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }

    function setManager(address manager, bool state) public ownerOnly {
        managers[manager] = state;
    }
}
```

Then just inherit your Storage contract from Managed and add `managerOnly` modifier instead of `onlyOwner` to the `addTotalSupply`. After you deploy both Storage and Logic, connect them by calling.

```
await storage.setManager(logic.address, true).send({from:owner})
//rest of the code
```

Hope, that will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this may help with my problem. I will try and let you know. One more help, if you know any detail document for creating upgradeable ERC20 contract please share here

Comment: The word `upgradeable` is quite broad. What particular behaviour do you want to implement?

Comment: I need to modify in mint(). I have maximum mintable limit. Mint is happens every day until it reach maximum circulation. For example first deploy, it mint based on one formula.but after some day i need to change the formula.

Comment: Think about moving that `mint` logic to another contract, say MintLogic. Token contract can store address of current MintLogic and you'll be able to change it later via some `changeLogic` method. Example. Token's mint() function is 
`{
  bool canMint = mintLogic.canMint(); 
  uint256 amount = mintLogic.getMintAmount; 
  if(canMint) {totalSupply += amount;}
}`